# Java regex - combining expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write code that returns a credit card vendor using regular expression, which seem to work, eg:

```
// Visa - always begins digit 4, 13 or 16 digits long
^[4].{12}|^[4].{15} 

// Visa Electron - begin with the code pattern, 16 digits long
4026.{12}|417500.{10}|4405.{12}|4508.{12}|4844.{12}|4913.{12}|4917.{12}
```

So for a method isVisa I want the regex to say *"return Visa based on the Visa regex, but not Visa Electron"*

This code does not work:

```
    public static String isVisa(String number) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[4].{12}|^[4].{15}&&(!4026.{12}|!417500.{10}|!4405.{12}|!4508.{12}|!4844.{12}|!4913.{12}|!4917.{12})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(number);
    if (m.matches()) return "Visa";
    else return "";
}
```

Comment: FYI You need length 16-19 and Visa overlaps Eletcron in many ranges, to do this properly you need a regularly updated lookup table of BIN ranges (I was doing something similar last week)

Comment: Wouldn't the last line be better for `return m.matches() ? "Visa" : "";`

Comment: This seems like a boolean function to me.  You might want to return a boolean here instead of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) method validates the regular expression against the entire string, so you do not need the start `^` and end `$` anchors. Also the regular expression engine is matching these characters `&!` as literals, which it seems you are trying to use them as operators.

To ignore those patterns you can use a **Negative Lookahead** to achieve this.

```
(?!.*(?:(?:4026|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917).{12}|417500.{10}))(?=4.{12}|4.{15}).*
```

**Example**: This returns `true` for the first two since the rest are not valid for your case.

```
String[] numbers = { "4000236512341234", "4000222213232222", "4026122222222222", 
                     "4175000000000000", "4405343434344343", "4508111111111111",
                     "4844000000000000", "4913000000000000", "4917000000000000" };

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?!.*(?:(?:4026|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917).{12}|417500.{10}))(?=4.{12}|4.{15}).*");

for (String x: numbers) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}
```

**Output**:

```
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use positive and negative lookaheads to check for the lines which starts with some numbers and doesn't starts with some specific numbers.

```
^(?!417500.{10}|4026.{12}|4405.{12}|4508.{12}|4844.{12}|4913.{12}|4917.{12})(?=4.{12}|4.{15}).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cB9eI0)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a very simple and easy to understand regex:

```
4026.{12}|417500.{10}|4405.{12}|4508.{12}|4844.{12}|4913.{12}|4917.{12}|([4].{12}|[4].{15})
```

This will match all the Visa Electron patterns without capturing anything. When you get a match, check capture group one isn't `null` for it to be Visa.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589204/1691146) for a great explanation of the technique.